# Logging with Specflow and xUnit 2 (ITestOutputHelper)

Tags: c#, specflow, xunit, xunit2

Unfortunately I have a Specflow test passing locally, but it fails on the VSO Build vNext server, and I really need to see verbose information during the test run so I can figure out what is going on.

But I'm struggling to try to inject `ITestOutputHelper` into a Specflow binding like so

`public SomeSteps(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)`

but Specflow complains with the message

`BoDi.ObjectContainerException Interface cannot be resolved: Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper (resolution path: ...)`

How on earth can view log and view output during a Specflow test?

Comment: can't you just `Trace.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine` in your steps?

Comment: Described in the link that @Avalanchis provided in another comment. but unfortunately xUnit2 doesn't capture Trace and Debug output. You have to use ITestOutputHelper. [rant on] I'm starting to dislike xUnit.net more and more. Even on github there seems to be only a very few contributors and not many commits and replies to address the issues that have been reported. [rant off]

Answer (score 3):

not sure if I'm using a newer version and it's easier now, but this seems to work for me:

```
ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioContainer.Resolve<ITestOutputHelper>().WriteLine("Hello");
```

Comment: This worked for me -- also note that you can obtain the ScenarioContext in via Dependency Injection (DI) in .NET Core instead of using ScenarioContext.Current.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could come up with, it's not ideal but it does accomplish what you want.

You create a new class that implements your generated xunit class.  In my example, the generated class is called `YourNormalFeatureClass`

```
public class SpecialTest : YourNormalFeatureClass
{
    private Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper helper;

    public SpecialTest(ITestOutputHelper helper) : base()
    {
        this.helper = helper;   
    }

    public override void ScenarioSetup(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
    {
        base.ScenarioSetup(scenarioInfo);

        // you'd want a better way to keep track of this string
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner().ScenarioContext.Set(this.helper, "helper");
    }

}
```

Now, you're able to access your XUnit `ITestOutputHelper` from within your steps file via

```
var helper = this._scenarioContext.Get<Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper>("helper");
helper.WriteLine("output from within the steps file that will be written to xunit!");
```

You'd need to be defensive with that `helper` variable to make sure that you don't get any `NullReferenceException`'s

The downside to this is that you now have 2 copies of the same test because you inherited the old test.  So in this case you have the tests from `SpecialTest` and `YourNormalFeatureClass`.  This means that you'd need to not run `YourNormalFeatureClass` tests and only run the `SpecialTest` tests.

All of this would be easily solved if SpecFlow allowed you to customize the code generation process.  That way you could expose the `ITestOutputHelper` via the generated code.  The consumption of it from within the steps would be the same.

Comment: There's a pull request waiting since August which does exactly this: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/689

Comment: That's awesome, pitty they aren't pulling it in

Answer (score 1):

This may be a new addition to SpecFlow since this question was asked (6 years ago), but [TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.ISpecFlowOutputHelper](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/outputapi/outputapi.html#output-api) should solve your problem. Inject it and use it in much the same way you would with xUnit's ITestOutputHelper, e.g.

```
[Binding]
public class SomeSteps
{
    private readonly ISpecFlowOutputHelper output;

    public SomeSteps(ISpecFlowOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    [When(@"I write some debug info")]
    public void WhenIWriteSomeDebugInfo()
    {
        this.output.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the parallel-running framework you can't use a static ScenarioContext anymore, but you can use:

```
var console= _scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.Resolve<ISpecFlowOutputHelper>();
```

Ref: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/Parallel-Execution.html#xunit-configuration